# I opened a terminal, put my whole command in quotes and it replied “command not found”. What is going on?

Tags: command-line, fish

I got this when I opened the terminal:

```text
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
leah@leah-pc ~>
```

... and I then tried to run a command:

```text
leah@leah-pc ~> 'dpkg --configure -a' 
dpkg --configure -a: command not found
```

... which didn't work as expected. What do I do next?

Comment: You've not provided basic details such as what Ubuntu product, and release of that product you're using. Ubuntu Core for example does not have a `dpkg` command (it's a *snap* only version of Ubuntu).

Comment: You appear to be running the command inside single quotes with the quotes included like `'dpkg --configure -a' `  ... and that will pass the whole command including its options and arguments to be passed to the shell as a single token and handled as such ... That won't work ... Try removing the quotes instead like `dpkg --configure -a` and it should work.

Comment: @karel no, the OP here ran the command quoted, look at the error message.

Comment: Imma be real here...as a very experienced professional software developer who literally spends hours every day at the command line I love fish shell, but I question whether it's appropriate for a non-expert. Be aware that many, many things you will want to copy-paste from the internet are not going to work as-is in fish. I recommend maybe using something like bash or zsh until you have enough experience to decide whether fish is right for you. My $0.02.

Comment: Tangentially, you might want to use `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Most `dpkg` commands will not work without administrator privileges.

Answer (score 11):

You appear to be running the command inside single quotes with the quotes included like `'dpkg --configure -a'` (*double quotes `"..."` will result in the same as well*) ... and that will result in the whole command including its options and arguments to be read by the shell as a single token and handled as such i.e. the shell will try to call the command `dpkg --configure -a` instead of calling the command `dpkg` and passing it the options `--configure` and `-a` ... That won't work.

Try removing the quotes instead like `dpkg --configure -a` and use it with `sudo` as that operation requires elevated privileges to run like so:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

... and it should work.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for understanding a Mom that had no Idea, yet it was so easy. Many hugs to you!!!